# Linux workstation in LAN suddenly cannot access WAN

Tags: linux, home-networking

In my LAN I have a few devices and workstations. The workstations run Linux and were able to access WAN without issues. Suddenly one of my workstations can no longer access WAN but can access the LAN. No major configuration changes have been made aside from the basic apt-get update and upgrade.

The router used is TL-WR841N.

Doing a tcpdump shows that there is a 100% loss of packets for connections to WAN.

Pinging to any other hosts in the LAN, including the gateway is fine. Pinging something like google.com or 8.8.8.8 does not work.

What could have caused this and how can this be troubleshot.

EDIT: Upgraded packages

```
Start-Date: 2016-12-01  22:08:08
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3), python-samba:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 (0.10.3
1-3+nmu1ubuntu5, 0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5.2), gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64 (0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5, 0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5.2), isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.2.4-7ubuntu12.7, 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.8), firef
ox-locale-en:amd64 (49.0.2+linuxmint1+rosa, 50.0+linuxmint1+rosa), python3.4:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5), vim-common:amd64 (7.4.052-1ubuntu3, 7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1), fir
efox:amd64 (49.0.2+linuxmint1+rosa, 50.0+linuxmint1+rosa), samba:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), python3.4-minimal:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4, 3.4.3-1ubun
tu1~14.04.5), libgs9-common:amd64 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4, 9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.5), libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5), python2.7:amd64 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2, 
2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3), libpython3.4:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5), gstreamer1.0-tools:amd64 (1.2.4-0ubuntu1, 1.2.4-0ubuntu1.1), gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:amd64 (0.10.31-3+nm
u1ubuntu5, 0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5.2), samba-dsdb-modules:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4, 9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.5), l
ibpython3.4-minimal:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5), samba-common-bin:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.6-8u
buntu0.2, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3), libmagickwand5:amd64 (6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.1, 6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.3), libc-ares2:amd64 (1.10.0-2, 1.10.0-2ubuntu0.1), vim-tiny:amd64 (7.4.052-1ubuntu3, 7.4.052-1ubuntu3.
1), samba-libs:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3), gstreamer0.10-gconf:amd64 (0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5, 0.1
0.31-3+nmu1ubuntu5.2), imagemagick:amd64 (6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.1, 6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.3), isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.2.4-7ubuntu12.7, 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.8), gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 (1.2.4-1~ubuntu1
, 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1.3), smbclient:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.2.4-1~ubuntu1, 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1.3), vim:amd64 (7.4.052
-1ubuntu3, 7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1), libgs9:amd64 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4, 9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.5), libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 (1.2.4-0ubuntu1, 1.2.4-0ubuntu1.1), libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (1.2.4-0ubuntu1, 
1.2.4-0ubuntu1.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 (1.2.4-1~ubuntu1, 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1.3), python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3), libmagickcore5:amd64 (6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.1,
 6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.3), gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64 (1.2.4-0ubuntu1, 1.2.4-0ubuntu1.1), imagemagick-common:amd64 (6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.1, 6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.3), libwbclient0:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubunt
u0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-101.148, 3.13.0-103.150), libc-ares-dev:amd64 (1.10.0-2, 1.10.0-2ubuntu0.1), ghostscript:amd64 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4, 9.
10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.5), samba-common:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2, 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3), vim-runtime:amd64 (7.4.05
2-1ubuntu3, 7.4.052-1ubuntu3.1), libsmbclient:amd64 (4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), tar:amd64 (1.27.1-1, 1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2016-12-01  22:09:34

Start-Date: 2016-12-04  18:35:03
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (50.0+linuxmint1+rosa, 50.0.2+linuxmint1+rosa), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (54.0.2840.100-1, 55.0.2883.75-1), ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (0.2.91.4linuxmint1, 0
.2.91.12linuxmint1), firefox:amd64 (50.0+linuxmint1+rosa, 50.0.2+linuxmint1+rosa)
End-Date: 2016-12-04  18:35:25
```

Comment: Can you expand your question to clarify what changed, and when?  What was upgraded with apt-get?  Can you run the following commands from a host that works, and a host that does not work: `route` (that should provide a default gateway) and `ping $DEFAULT-GATEWAY-IP`  (where $DEFAULT-GATEWAY-IP is the ip address identified by the default line in the output of `route`).  You could also try to identify the ip adddress of a remote site (like www.google.com) and identify the ip address of another host on the LAN.  Can LAN hosts all ping each other? Can they all ping www.google.com?

Comment: Yes, the workstation can access the LAN including the gateway. All attempts to connect to WAN, including pings don't work. Every other workstation can ping and access WAN. I am not sure what changed since last update.

Comment: Nevermind, found the apt logs.

Comment: @drum Can you add the `route` result, and the `ifconfig` result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the router. Solved the issue by flashing OpenWRT.